# Is there a Skein implementation that works on on AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, hash, aws-lambda, python-c-api, skein

Is it possible to implement a Skein tree hash across AWS lambda functions?
In other words using Lambda functions for parallelism.

Comment: Did you try some solution? If yes, can you post the code, please?

Comment: Sorry, I have not.
My hope was that someone has developed a Python C-extension that allows for the tree hash to be distributed via Lambda functions. So far everything I've seen is used to spin up cores or threads.